# POSIX test and -a

Tags: shell, shell-script, posix, test

I checked a script of mine with [checkbashisms](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkbaskisms/) and I got the following warnings:

```
possible bashism in check_ssl_cert line 821 (test -a/-o):
if [ -n "${ALTNAMES}" -a -n "${COMMON_NAME}" ] ; then
```

In [section 4.62.4 of the POSIX specs](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/posix/PCD2/TITLE.HTM) I find

> primary -a primary     Performs a binary and of the results of primary and primary. The -a operator has precedence over the -o operator.

Why are `-a` and `-o` considered non-portable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not so much that it is not portable, but that there's no `[` implementation where it is reliable when passed more than 4 arguments.

Even in bash:

```
$ ALTNAMES='='  bash -c '[ -n "${ALTNAMES}" -a -n "${COMMON_NAME}" ]'
bash: line 0: [: too many arguments
```

The related section states:

> **>4 arguments**:
>
> The results are unspecified.
>
> [OB XSI] [Option Start] On XSI-conformant systems, combinations of primaries and operators shall be evaluated using the precedence and associativity rules described
>   previously. In addition, the string comparison binary primaries '=' and "!=" shall have a higher precedence than any unary primary. [Option End]

`-a` and `-o` should be banned. The right way is to use the `&&` and `||` **shell** operators instead:

```
if [ -n "$foo" ] && [ -n "$bar" ]; then
```

I even find it more legible.

Comment: Thanks, so the only solution would be to have two tests? `if [ -n "${ALTNAMES}" ] && [ -n "${COMMON_NAME} ] ;

Comment: Not the _only_ one but certainly the best and recommended as a replacement for `-a` and `-o`

Comment: Ok many thanks (with only I meant that there is no way to have a single test ...).

Comment: Yes, you could do `[ "x$ALTNAMES" != x -a "x$COMMON_NAME" != x ]` (still unspecified as per POSIX but portable and reliable), or `[ "${ALTNAMES:+x}${COMMON_NAME:+x}" = xx ]`

Answer (score 2):

Because they are an XSI extension, which may or not be implemented. See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html