# Display files to size with lower and upper bound without using `find`

Tags: linux, bash, files, test

I need to create a program via `vim` in Linux called `between`. The script takes two arguments as the lower bound and upper bound of the file size, and prints out a list of file names as well as their sizes. However, I can't use the `find` command to complete this script.

I have gotten this far: to display all the files; but I can't seem to display specific ones WITHOUT `find`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *
do
    set -- $(ls -l "$i")
    echo $i: $5 bytes
done
```

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures, use [code blocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) instead.

Comment: I changed it to make more sense for people, my apologies, I'm new to this

Comment: It's okay. Welcome to StackExchange ;)

Comment: What prevents you from using find?

Comment: it was stated in the question to not use terms we have not covered which was `find`

Comment: Try not to move the goalposts on your question. People will be answering the version of the question that you asked, not every update along the way.  Also, use shellcheck.net to get past syntax errors (your brackets).

Comment: Also, **please [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943)** — there is *no way* to do it 100% reliably.  Bad, bad habit.  Please just don't.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in *
do
  size=$(stat --format="%s" "$i")
  if [ $size -gt $1 -a $size -lt $2 ]
  then
    printf "Right-sized: %s\n" "$i"
  else
    printf "Wrong-sized: %s\n" "$i"
  fi
done
```

This is just an update to your loop, but instead of parsing ls, it uses stat to gather the file's size, in bytes.

This snippet assumes that you've already sanity-checked $1 and $2 -- I didn't want to do *all* of your homework for you!

Comment: As I suspect you know, it's safer to put `$size`, `$1`, and `$2` in quotes — although if you trust `stat` to give sane output, and if you have validated `$1` and `$2` before the loop, it's not so critical.  But why are you using `printf "…%n…"`?  That doesn't work for me.

Comment: Auugh, thanks G-man -- overzealous edit on my own part. I should clarify my assumptions as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- To check for range you could use an `if` statement or a `continue` operation:

  ```
  if [[ $z -ge $1 || $z -le $2 ]]
  then
      : print result
  fi
  ```

  or

  ```
  [[ $z -lt $1 || $z -gt $2 ]] && continue
  : print result
  ```
- Depending on needs, the test options are:

  - `-ge`: Greater than or equal to
  - `-le`: Less than or equal to
  - `-lt`: Less than
  - `-gt`: Greater than
- Use `stat`, `du` or `ls` to get the size. The two latter would require a check to see if target is a directory or regular file as well:

  ```
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]
  then
      : a regular file
  fi
  ```

  or, to prevent nesting of if's:

  ```
  ! [[ -f "$f" ]] && continue
  ```

  with file sizes, for example, either of:

  ```
  z=$(stat -c%s "$f")
  z=$(du -b "$f" | cut -f1)
  z=$(ls -l "$f" | cut -d' ' -f5)
  ```
- To print the result you could use `printf` to get a more clean printout. I.e. fixed with of size etc. [Also read this.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/98945)
- If you really want to be nice, validate the arguments as well ...

---

```
#!/bin/bash

usage()
{
    printf "Usage: %s <min-size> <max-size>\n" "$0" >&2
    exit 1
}

! [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && usage
! [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && usage


for f in *
do
    z=$(stat -c%s "$f")

    # Alternatives to get size:
    # ! [[ -f "$f" ]] && continue
    # z=$(du -b "$f" | cut -f1)
    # z=$(ls -l "$f" | cut -d' ' -f5)

    if [[ $z -ge $1 || $z -le $2 ]]
    then
        printf "%11d %s\n" "$z" "$f"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a condition, which in shell has the following syntax:

```
if TEST
then
    ACTION
else
    ACTION
fi
```

For tests, it's common to employ `[`. For example, to check if `$5` is greater than 25 but is less than 50, you'll write:

```
if [ "$5" -gt 25 ] && [ "$5" -lt 50 ]
then
    echo "It's greater than 25 but is less than 50"
else
    echo "It's either <= 25, or >= 50, or not a number at all"
fi
```

Don't forget the quotes (thanks @Wildcard for the reminder) and [don't pass](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57840/posix-test-and-a/57843#57843) `[` more than four arguments (thanks @Jeff Schaller for the link.)

Check out [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) and [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html), they are a good reference.

(Note, though, that there are shells other than Bash, and their syntax and capabilities might differ.)

Comment: so just to clarify things, you are suggesting for me to use two if statements to imply an upper and lower bound of bytes and echo it?

Comment: @AlexanderBatischev, **don't forget to [quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)**.  Especially as you are teaching someone new to shell scripting.  I would also recommend avoiding `[ ... -a ... ]` in favor of `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` for better readability.

Comment: @Wildcard - it's not a factor here, but I remember seeing a comment from Stephane that `-a` could be ambiguous if the next item evaluated to to a 'test' operator instead of an operand. I believe their recommendation was to convert over to the [] && [] format. [found it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57843/117549)

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I'll update the post and then delete my comments so that not to mislead other people.

Comment: Nice.  :)  You might also consider changing the message for the `else` condition.  You only know that it's *not* greater than 25 and lesser than 50.  You don't know (a) whether it's exactly 25 or 50, nor (b) whether it's a number at all.  ;)  (Other code may guarantee a number there but I'm just looking at your code snippet on its own.)